# Openstack release name

Tags: openstack

I am not able to determine the Openstack release running on my machine. I tried to match the output of nova package version with release naming site. But my nova version does not have a match.

```
stack@Selm:~$  nova-manage  --version

12.0.0
```

This package is not listed on following release site:
https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Releases

Could someone please tell me how can I determine the release name running on my machine?

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: dpkg did not provide any ouput. 

    stack@Selm:~$ dpkg-query -W nova-common
    dpkg-query: no packages found matching nova-common
    stack@Selm:~$

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're not on Kilo, because it looks like with Kilo that `nova-manage --version` returns something more useful:

```
# nova-manage --version
2015.1.0
```

And in fact it looks like this is true for Juno and Icehouse as well.

If you installed OpenStack using your system's package manager you will probably get better information by querying the packaging system.  For example, on an `rpm` based system such as Red Hat or Fedora you could run:

```
# rpm -q openstack-nova
```

Which might return:

```
openstack-nova-common-2015.1.0-3.el7.noarch
```

Which tells us that I am using the 2015.1.0 release, [aka "Kilo"](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Releases).

You could do something similar on an Ubuntu (or Debian) system using `dpkg-query -W nova-common`, which might give you:

```
1:2014.1.5-0ubuntu1
```

Which would indicate "Icehouse".

Comment: dpkg did not provide any ouput. 

    stack@Selm:~$ dpkg-query -W nova-common
    dpkg-query: no packages found matching nova-common
    stack@Selm:~$

Comment: Well, because you don't have that package installed.  This may mean OpenStack was installed from source, not from packages.  Does the `--version` output from everything else provide the same result as `nova-manage`?

Comment: stack@Selma-vRR:~$ keystone-manage --version
8.0.0
stack@Selma-vRR:~$ glance-manage --version
11.0.0
stack@Selma-vRR:~$ swift-manage --version
swift-manage: command not found
stack@Selma-vRR:~$ cinder-manage --version
7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Since your install is not from a package, go to https://github.com/openstack/nova. Look at the file named 'setup.cfg'. This is where the version number comes from. Choose the 'switch branches/tags' drop down to look at older versions. You will find your version listed at some point.

12.0.0 matches 'master' BTW. This was changed on Jun 16th so you have a recent (ish) checkout from Git.

Answer (score 0):

From what i figured out, till the release "Kilo" you can do "nova-manage --version" and match the same with the entry in "https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Releases". But after Kilo version, the output of the above command would be something like this "12.0.3". This output maps to Liberty. 12 --> Liberty 13 --> Mitaka,etc

Answer (score 0):

The resource provided in the previous responses is not updated. OpenStack releases are now available at https://releases.openstack.org/